# .wav audio files will not play - Javascript

Tags: javascript, html, audio, wav

I am having trouble playing a .wav file.
This is my code for fetching the file:

`var tableHitSound = new Audio("707 Rim.wav");`

And for playing it:

```
tableHitSound.load();
tableHitsound.play();
```

There are no errors in this code, and it finds the file fine, however it does not play the file i.e I dont hear anything.

`console.log(tableHitSound.duration);`
Returns `NaN`

`console.log(tableHiSound.ended);`
Returns `false`

Is there anything I am doing wrong?

Comment: At least you're missing a closing `"`.

Comment: @Roope sorry, bad copy and pasting :)

Comment: which codec? (I think that [only PCM is supported](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Supported_media_formats#WAVE_PCM))

Answer (score 0):

Two possible solutions:

- `tableHitsound.play();` -- 's' in 'sound' is lower case here but as upper case in variable initialization
- Make sure it is 16bit wav format

Comment: It must have something to do with it not being 16bit format. I tried other wav filed, and the ones that worked were those that were longer than a few seconds.